# Crystal selection formula that would bring based on first parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I'm trying to find a formula that would bring me records based of the first two parameter from the selection tothen followed by other parameters in the formula based off the first two parameters selected. So this is what I have so far.The problem that I’m running into is that if not all formulas are selected then I got nothing to print on the report. So if I select {Sig1} and {Sig4} the report comes up blank.

```
{table.client} = {?client#} and
{table.signature1} = {?Sig1}
//to then bring only the below selected parameters based from the {client#} and {?Sig1}
parameters. Not all parameters will be selected as well.
({table.signature2} = {?Sig2} or {?Sig2} = "") or
({table.signature3} = {?Sig3} or {?Sig3} = "") or
({table.signature4} = {?Sig4} or {?Sig4} = "")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance. 
Hope I was clear

Comment: do you need to test for null parameter values instead of blank?

Comment: The thing is that I'm giving the option to the user to leave any parameter SIG2- SIG4 blank because the report parameter drop down would show a null value or if there is a value not to be selected as well.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. You don't use any connective between the first and second parts of your formula (after you check {?Sig1}). I'm guessing this is a typo since CR would give you an error.
2. The parentheses do nothing since OR operators are commutative. This is confusing to read and likely is at least partially responsible for the next problem...
3. Only one of the statements after the comments needs to evaluate to TRUE in order for the whole portion beneath the comments to evaluate to TRUE. So if you put in a value for {?Sig2} but left {?Sig3} blank, you'd still return all records because `{?Sig3}=""` evaluates to TRUE. To fix this, you need to use an AND-operator between each line.

```
{table.client} = {?client#}
and {table.signature1} = {?Sig1}
and ({table.signature2} = {?Sig2} or {?Sig2} = "") //note that the parens are required here
and ({table.signature3} = {?Sig3} or {?Sig3} = "") // since AND takes precedence
and ({table.signature4} = {?Sig4} or {?Sig4} = "")
```